# Delete all of relationship with static::deleting model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've tried using event handler for delete the relation but it can't work for delete relation of relation. Event hasMany Person and Person hasMany File

```
class Event
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        static::deleting(function($model) { // before delete() method call this
            $model->person()->delete();
        });
    }
}

class Person
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        static::deleting(function($model) { // before delete() method call this
            $model->files()->delete();
        });
    }
}
```

So when I delete event, it can delete person but it doesn't delete the files row. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call it one by one to call boot method on each model instance. So, get the instances and then delete them one by one.

```
class Event
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        static::deleting(function($model) { // before delete() method call this
            foreach($model->person as $person){
              $person->delete();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
class Person
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        static::deleting(function($model) { // before delete() method call this
            foreach($model->files as $file){
              $file->delete();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So, i can't delete it in one line like i put?

Comment: No. You can define deletion in your migration like `->onDelete('cascade')` as stated [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: I see. So it refer to this warning right? "When issuing a mass update or delete query via Eloquent, the saved, updated, deleting, and deleted model events will not be dispatched for the affected models. This is because the models are never actually retrieved when performing mass updates or deletes."